# How to exclude apostrophe and comma in python regex

Tags: python, regex

I m trying to remove a ' and a , from Python regexp

I came up with:

```
regex = re.compile("[^']*\.dbf[^,]*")

file_handle = open(file)
for line in file_handle:
    m = regex.match(line)
    if m:
        print m.group()
```

So that I would have the following matching string

```
/u01/app/data/ORCL/system01.dbf
```

instead of

```
 [blank spaces]'/u01/app/data/ORCL/system01.dbf',
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
regex = re.compile(r"[^'](*\.dbf)'?[^,]*")
```

i think you missed the matching ', and the result should be m.group(1)

should be:

```
regex = re.compile(r"([^']*\.dbf)'?[^,]*")
```

Comment: Almost got it with minor correction:

regex = re.compile(r"[^']*(.*\.dbf)'?[^,]*")

But still I m getting:

'/u01/app/data/ORCL/system01.dbf (leading ')

Comment: ==> re.compile(r"([^']*\.dbf)'?[^,]*")

Comment: I finally managed to do it))) by: re.compile(r"[^']*'?(.*\.dbf)'?[^,]*"). Thanks for your help!! Greetings from Russia! )) :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
>>> fn='            "/u01/app/data/ORCL/system01.dbf,"'
>>> re.search(r'([\w\./]+)',fn).group(1)
'/u01/app/data/ORCL/system01.dbf'
```